# Grouping Enums best practice

Tags: c#, enums

If you have an enum where the values can be naturally grouped into subsets. For example:

```
[Flags]
public enum Instrument
{
    Lute,
    Guitar,
    Flute,
    Drum
}
[Flags]
public enum InstrumentType
{
    Percussion,
    String,
    Wind,
}
```

there are many ways this can be accomplished

1) To combine this data into a separate Enum?

```
[Flags]
public enum ValidInstrument
{
    Lute= Instrument.Lute| InstrumentType.String,
    Guitar = Instrument.Guitar | InstrumentType.String,
    Flute = Instrument.Flute | InstrumentType.Wind,
    Drum = Instrument.Drum | InstrumentType.Percussion,
}
```

(assuming appropriate and none crossing values between the enums)
which would allow you to do

```
(ValidInstrument | InstrumentType.String) == InstrumentType.String
```

to determine if a instrument is string or not

2) to create some sort of mapping structure that does exactly the same thing?

```
public static InstrumentType GetInstrumentType(Instrument inst)
{
    switch(inst)
    {
    case Instrument.Lute:
    case Instrument.Guitar:
        return InstrumentType.String
    //etc.
    }
}
```

3) Attributes?

```
public enum Instrument
{
    [InstrumentType(InstrumentType.String)]
    Lute,
    [InstrumentType(InstrumentType.String)]
    Guitar,
    [InstrumentType(InstrumentType.Wind)]
    Flute,
    [InstrumentType(InstrumentType.Percussion)]
    Drum
}
```

4) in a standalone class?

```
public class ValidInstrument
{
public InstrumentType Type{get;set;}
public Instrument Instrument{get;set;}
}
```

with a static runtime population

which of these methods is better, or if dependent on the situation what factors should influence the choice

Comment: Why are you set on doing a hierarchy with an enum?

Comment: @blam this is a common situation i come up against. the data is hierarchical but also simplistic and finite. there are an exact fixed number of options that apart from the grouping no other information is required. what i'm trying to determine is how this data should be handled and why

Comment: Just because it is common, hierarchical, simplistic, and finite does not mean it should be done with an enumeration.  This only works for 2 levels and not amenable to LINQ.

Comment: in that case the answer would be 4, its not suitable for Enum and should be represented in a class.

Comment: as you can see from the question i've found many ways that i could make this work, none of them feel correct though. as each of them seems to have more disadvantages than advantages. which is why i have asked the question so i can find out the right way to do this not the cludge. if the right way isn't one of my suggestions then feel free to suggest a 5th or 6th method

Comment: Does not mean enum is the right answer for 2.   And for sure your number 4 is not the best solution.  There is nothing that limits those properties to enforce a hierarchy.   There is this whole thing called Inheritance that does exactly this that you are missing.

Comment: How would you enforce the Hierarchy in inheritance? yes i could define a instrument class as a parent for a wind class, but there would no way to enforce that you cant create a stringed instrument called a Flute, and that would then lose the ability for the code to check for a predefined instrument called a Flute unless you followed the Media.Colors model where you define a static class that pretends to be an enum?

Comment: @MikeT You can make the constructor private, and just have a fixed list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As soon as you start talking about relationships between things, it feels like you are talking about inheritance. Best practice would be to represent this as a class structure.

```
class Instrument
{
    void Play();
}

class StringedInstrument : Instrument
{
    void Strum();
}

class Guitar : StringedInstrument
{
}
```

With factory classes/methods and a few other design patterns you should be able to handle the same things and an enum lets you, but also many more that you could never handle with an enum.

If you want to find all band members who play a stringed instrument, you would simply get all members where their instrument "is a" stringed instrument. This should be able to be done in C# with a `Type.IsSubclassOf()` call.

If a developer then creates a `Flute` class that inherits from `StringedInstrument`, as in your comment above, you should fire that developer! :) If you are talking about assigning a `Flute` object to a `StringedInstrument` instance, that would be prevented by C# because the cast is invalid. You can cast a `Flute` to `WindInstrument` or `Instrument`, but never `StringedInstrument` unless a developer incorrectly made it inherit from the wrong instrument type.

Comment: Once you go far enough down the route that you have taken a Fixed list of values and turned it into a completely customisable Heirachical structure. then you might as well take the next step and allow a maintenance screen to creation and deletion of objects by end users. and trust me there is nothing they are not capable of doing and then blaming you for

Comment: However the Consensus seems to be that an enum should never be grouped enums iand should be avoided in which case as you correctly point out 4) create a class that represents the hierarchy seems to be the correct answer

Comment: But lets give the consensus check to the later answer.

Comment: @Blam i gave the answer here because whiel you are both saying the same thing the way he has said it is clearer and easier to understand, the level of inheritance provided here as in yours in inappropriate to the use, it would be sufficient to have Guitar as an Instance of StringedInstrument making the guitar class completely pointless

Comment: @MikeT I agree completely about users! But for something that is fairly fixed (i.e. not that many new ones being created all the time), hopefully it is acceptable to lock it down somewhat to prevent some of this pain.

Answer (score 1):

Because `[Flags]` indicates that `enum` values may be stored as bits, using comments for grouping rather than separate data structures is one way of balancing potential readability with potential performance...and why use `[Flags]` but for performance reasons?

Comment: if using the composite enum method bit wise comparison is the only way to decode the compound values into their constituents, and if your using bitwise comparison then [Flags] should always be marked. of the 4 methods i've suggested only the first requires the [Flags]

Comment: Just as an example say you have a list of people that play an instrument and want to only select those that play a wind instrument then a comment will not let you do this,.as you wouldn't want to check against every single wind instrument every time you wanted to make the check. like wise having a person play a Wind instrument  wouldn't be a instrument only a category of instrument

Comment: At some point you have to stop decomposition, the piccolo and contrabassoon are both woodwinds...and cannons are percussion. The breakdown should accommodate reasonable anticipated queries, such as "what are instruments the orchestra needs to ship by truck".

Answer (score 1):

If you are just trying to manage a simple relationship then

```
Dictionary<Instrument, InstrumentType>
```

If you need to strictly enforce then Inheritance

```
public class Guitar : StringInsturment
```

I get that could have enum hierarchy but I just don't get what real life solution it solves.  So Guitar has a Description of String.  By the time you  wrap some code around that to do something with it you would be better off with class inheritance.

Comment: I see where you are coming from now, but classes are supposed to be for generic objects that share the same behaviour so if i was going to have lots of different makes of guitar and was also going to have a list of Violin makes. but if there is only ever going to be a single guitar or violin instance then Encapsulating that as a object rather than as a instance of instrument would be an incorrect use of inheritence

Comment: you wouldn't Create a Mark class as a child of Person just so you could state that Mark is a person

Comment: The Dictionary approach would work though if it was static and readonly and populated at runtime will all possible values. its a example of 4 only using the generic KeyValuePair insteard of a custom class

Comment: Just one does make it an incorrect use inheritance.

Comment: This is clearly going no where.  Sorry I tired to help.  What part of Guitar : String limits Guitar to Sting is not clear?